# Can I select rows from two tables using t1 rows as key for t2 rows?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

id1, id2, ... idX contains id from t2 or null. Can I make such select, which will put params from t2 in t1?

For example i have a t1(name,year,id1,id2,id3,id4) values:

```
name    year    id1    id2    id3    id4
------------------------------------------
marko    1999    1       2    null    1
polo     1985    null    null     5    3
```

And t2 values:

```
id    info    param
--------------------------------------
1    apple    green
2    car    yellow
3    bee    pink
4    doctor     whiskey
5    book    small
```

So I'd like to have such dynamical query results, based on t1 rows:

```
SELECT name, year, id1-info, id1-param, id2-info, id2-param, id4-info, id4-param 
 FROM t1 WHERE name = 'marko'

SELECT name, year, id3-info, id3-param, id4-info, id4-param 
 FROM t1 WHERE name = 'marko'
```

I googled a lot, but found nothing except nested queries, such as:

```
SELECT 
  name, 
  year, 
  (SELECT `info` FROM t2 WHERE id = t1.id1) AS id1-info, 
  (SELECT `param` FROM t2 WHERE id = t1.id1) AS id1-param,
  (SELECT `info` FROM t2 WHERE id = t1.id2) AS id2-info...
```

But I understand, that it is a very bad idea, because I have a lot of id columns in t1, which are not static. Or if it cannot be done dynamically, can I just make SELECT, which will show me all in one row:

```
SELECT name, year, id1-info, id1-param, id2-info, id2-param, id3-info, id3-param, id4-info, id4-param 
 FROM t1 WHERE name = 'marko'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use one select in one row, you can use mulitple left join on t2.

```
SELECT name, 
       `year`, 
       id11.info as `id1-info`, 
       id11.param as `id1-param`, 
       id21.info as `id2-info`, 
       id21.param as `id2-param`, 
       id31.info as `id3-info`, 
       id31.param as `id3-param`, 
       id41.info as `id4-info`, 
      id41.param as `id4-param`
 FROM t1 
 LEFT JOIN t2 as id11 on t1.id1=id11.id
 LEFT JOIN t2 as id21 on t1.id2=id21.id
 LEFT JOIN t2 as id31 on t1.id3=id31.id
 LEFT JOIN t2 as id41 on t1.id4=id41.id
 WHERE name = 'marko';

  result:
  name  year    id1-info    id1-param   id2-info    id2-param   id3-info    id3-param   id4-info    id4-param
marko   1999    apple   green   car yellow  (null)  (null)  apple   green
```

Comment: Oh my, I never thought that it is OK to make multiple inner joins to one table.

Comment: yes it is as long as you put a different alias to each left join. if you like my answer pls accept/upvote it.